# Count unhidden lines from hide-lines?

Tags: lines

I want to count the number of lines shown with `hide-lines-matching`.

`count-lines` seems to return the wrong number.

`(length hide-lines-invisible-areas)` seems to be related in that we hide the regions between  the lines.

Comment: Does `(count-lines start end t)` return the right number? If so, do `C-h f count-lines` and read about the `IGNORE-INVISIBLE-LINES` optional argument.

Comment: Aha, that does  what I'm after. `(count-lines (point-min) (point-max) 't)` works great.

Comment: No quote required on `t` (or `nil` for that matter): it is a self-evaluating symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h f count-lines` says:

> (count-lines START END &optional IGNORE-INVISIBLE-LINES)
>
> ...
>
> When IGNORE-INVISIBLE-LINES is non-nil, invisible lines are not
> included in the count.

So, in order to count *visible* lines between `start` and `end`, use
`(count-lines start end t)`, setting the optional argument `IGNORE-INVISIBLE-LINES` to `t`.